# Не могу корректно поменять свойства display

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]   В  классе div я выбераю form-inline. Что бы содержимое дивов было в строчку. В итоге все улетает.
Нужно что -бы имя фамилия была вряд.

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  class="col-form-label">Имя</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Фамилия</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middleName">
                </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: <form class="form-inline"><div class="form-group mb-2">

Comment: в каком смысле улетает? куда улетает?

Comment: тег form не закрыт

Comment: ААА мои глаза! ЭМАЙЛ!!! ЭМАЙЛ!!!!! Развидьте мне это...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно объединить инпуты в один `<div class='form-group'>`:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="col-form-label">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName">
            <label class="col-form-label">Фамилия</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middleName">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял похоже, что вам надо так -

```
[ссылка на кодепен] https://codepen.io/uyuri/pen/OwJNOd
```

Все дело в бутстрапе и ваш html лучше разместить типа на кодепен чтобы было наглядно.
в бутстрапе col- это колонка сетки. а для [инлайновых](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms.asp) свойств нужно класс типа form-inline. Если объединить в один общий див но оставить бутстраповое col- все     равно будет разбиение на две строки

https://codepen.io/uyuri/pen/OwJNOd

Comment: @Anamnian ваш код работает на этой странице, но в кодепен - нет. разбивает на 2 блока

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4">Имя</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"Фамилия">
   </div>
```